# Tela branca na inicialização do app - Splash Screen

Tags: android

Criei uma tela inicial para o meu aplicativo usando uma atividade vazia que fica visível por 3 segundos com uma imagem de fundo. 
Normalmente, o aplicativo começa com uma tela branca antes que a imagem de fundo fique visível, no entanto, algumas aplicações já são iniciadas com a imagem de tela inicial "real".
Como implementar isso?

Comment: Edite a pergunta para postar o código que você utilizou para criar essa Activity de Splash. O Java e o XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro, crie um drawable com o seguinte conteúdo, sendo o nome dele background_splash:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/gray"/> <!--aqui pode ser qualquer coisa, até uma imagem-->
    <item>
        <bitmap 
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Feito isso, você vai no seu styles.xml colocar este trecho de código:

```
<style name="Splash" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
</style>
```

Depois, no seu manifest, você vai colocar o seguinte, na declaração da sua activity, lembrando que ela tem que ser a launcher e main do projeto:

```
<activity
    android:name=".SplashActivity"
    android:theme="@style/Splash">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />    
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Ai no onCreate da activity, você pode fazer todo o processamento necessário. Ela nem precisa ter a declaração do setContentView():

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Aqui você faz todo e qualquer processamento necessário, depois inicializa sua MainActivity e finaliza a splash, pra tirar ela do back stack.
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
```

Comment: nice bro!
you save my day!

Answer (score 1):

Só complementando a resposta do amigo acima, é necessário adicionar um delay ao criar a tela de Splash, se não o código irá carregar a MainActivity instantaneamente e a tela de Splash irá aparecer rapidamente.

Segue código de exemplo.

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Sim sim, por isso comentei que tem que colocar qualquer processamento antes de inicializar a activity. Além disso, delays deste tipo são contra as regras de design do google. Como chamadas, validações, dentre qualquer outras ações já consomem tempo, uma splash tem que ficar o menor tempo possível para o usuário, por isso recomenda-se utilizar somente o tempo necessário para processar e então já exibir o conteúdo real do app.

Comment: Correto. É que eu havia entendido que o processamento ao qual você se referia, estava relacionado apenas ao carregamento da tela principal.